# Insert query not inserting in database

Tags: php, mysql, insert

So I'm trying to insert some text into a already existing table. If I insert the text into the text field and press submit, I'll get a var_dump on a other page that shows the information that I want to insert but it doesnt send it to the database or something. I hope you can help me with what I'm doing wrong.

This is my insert query

```
public function insertComment($commentaar, $idBestelling){
    try{
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('UPDATE  `apotheek`.`Bestelling` SET  `commentaar` =  :commentaar WHERE  `Bestelling`.`idBestelling` = :idBestelling;');
            if($stmt->execute(array(
            ':commentaar' => $commentaar,
            ':idBestelling' => $idBestelling))){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    }
}
```

And here you can find the code from the webpage.

```
<div class="row">
<form role="form" method="post" action="/?content=bezorgen">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 loginborder">
    <h2 class="loginhead">Bestelling no. <?php print($data['idBestelling']); ?> <?php ($data['isSpoed'] == '0') ? print('') : print('deze bestelling is met SPOED') ?></h2>
    <hr>
    <div class="row col-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="loginhead">
            <h3>Commentaar</h3>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div>
        <textarea  rows="9" cols="74" name="commentaar"><?php print($data['commentaar']); ?></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row registerbtn">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12" style="text-align:right;"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verstuur" class="btn btn-lg" tabindex="5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

And the php

```
$data = $user->getBestellingPatient($_POST['idBestelling']);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $user->insertComment($_POST['commentaar'], $_POST['idBestelling']);
};
```

Comment: You are UPDATING, not INSERTING in your code. Are you sure this is correct, and the ID you are trying to updated exists?

Comment: The recoord already exists and comment has a value of 'NULL' so I want to update null into some text that im typing on the webpage

Comment: By the way you don't have any form/input element with the ID idBestelling. What exactly you are trying to get in $_POST['idBestelling'] ?

Comment: I dont know if $_POST['idBestelling'] is nessesary. I want to send the id to the query so it can fill in WHERE  `Bestelling`.`idBestelling` = :idBestelling;'

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to update a comment which is already exist in the database.

You should add a hidden field in the form to hold the id of the the post (Mostly auto incremented id from DB)

Add the below element below your textarea element

```
<input type='hidden' name='idBestelling'<?php print($data['idBestelling']); ?>/>
```

So when you are updating id will be passed as a part of the form then you can receive it usinig $_POST

Comment: If I do that, I can see idBestelling in my var_dump, it shows the id from the order that I selected but it doesnt change anything in the database.

Comment: That's the point right ? You are not inserting the value .. You are trying to update the post idBestelling might be the auto increment value i db ? So it won't change. It will make sure that you are updating the correct row in db.

Comment: Thats true. I understand what you are saying. This is to make sure im using the right id. But the value i try to update, stays the same, rather its NULL or something I changed in the databse

Comment: " This is to make sure im using the right id" - But where is the ID ? You are having null for all the idBestelling in database and your code says "WHERE  `Bestelling`.`idBestelling` = :idBestelling;'" but expecting something should happen.

Comment: No idBestelling is filled with the auto incremented id. Each order has its own id wich is filled with a number. The row 'commentaar' is empy and I would like to fill that one

Comment: Try to find out whats happening from the mysql side 
Query log: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html

print the query 
$statement->queryString.

Answer (score -1):

you should try this:

```
   $stmt = $this->_db->query('UPDATE  `apotheek`.`Bestelling` SET  `commentaar` =  :commentaar WHERE  `Bestelling`.`idBestelling` = :idBestelling;');
```

Comment: That doesnt help